# TensorFlow. Changes in code in CIFAR10 example are not reflected when I run cifar10_train.py

Tags: tensorflow

For example, I wanted to change the distortions in distorted_inputs. I commented out the random crops and the random flips. After doing so, I saved the file, and ran cifar10_train.py. I then ran TensorBoard, and viewed the images in the image visualizer. I realized that they are still flipped and cropped. This is something strange, as I have already edited the code, so it should not be happening. Any fixes?

```python
def distorted_inputs(data_dir, batch_size):
  """Construct distorted input for CIFAR training using the Reader ops.

  Args:
    data_dir: Path to the CIFAR-10 data directory.
    batch_size: Number of images per batch.

  Returns:
    images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
  """
  filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i)
               for i in xrange(1, 6)]
  for f in filenames:
    if not gfile.Exists(f):
      raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

  # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

  # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
  read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
  reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)
  distorted_image = reshaped_image

  height = IMAGE_SIZE
  width = IMAGE_SIZE

  # Image processing for training the network. Note the many random
  # distortions applied to the image.

  # Randomly crop a [height, width] section of the image.
  # distorted_image = tf.image.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width])

  # Randomly flip the image horizontally.
  # distorted_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(distorted_image)

  # Because these operations are not commutative, consider randomizing
  # randomize the order their operation.
  distorted_image = tf.image.random_brightness(distorted_image,
                                               max_delta=63)
  distorted_image = tf.image.random_contrast(distorted_image,
                                             lower=0.2, upper=1.8)

  # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
  float_image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(distorted_image)

  # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
  min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
  min_queue_examples = int(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN *
                           min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
  print ('Filling queue with %d CIFAR images before starting to train. '
         'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)

  # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
  return _generate_image_and_label_batch(float_image, read_input.label,
                                         min_queue_examples, batch_size)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Changing the lines at the top of each .py file, such as:

```
from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10
```

to

```
import cifar10
```

did the trick. I'm not too sure myself on why it works, but it's probably because doing such an import goes into python dist-packages. Looking forward to an answer from someone who knows exactly how this works!